# Count number of users with number of screens - SQL

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I have two tables, users and licenses
I want to retrieve number of users with the number of screens
e.g.

1 customer - 100 screens
2 customers - 30 screens
3 customers - 20 screens
5 customers - 4 screens

I've been trying to do it with a subquery but can't seem to get it right any help would be appreciated!

```
select count(0) as companies from users u where 
(select u.email, count(s.id) 
from users u 
join screens s on u.id = s.created_by
where u.deleted_at is null
and s.deleted_at is null
)
group by s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery here doesn't make sense - you're not pulling anything from users.

Try something like:

```
select count(0) as companies, sub1.counted_screens from
(select count(s.id) as counted_screens
from users u 
join screens s on u.id = s.created_by
where u.deleted_at is null
and s.deleted_at is null
) as sub1
group by sub1.counted_screens;
```